# sql db2 inner join comparing lookup values

Tags: sql, db2, inner-join

I have two tables like so:

Table_1

```
ID_1 | VALUES_1
1    | 123
2    | 234
3    | 345
```

Table_2

```
ID_2 | VALUES_2
1    | 123
2    | 234
3    | 349
4    | 456
5    | 567
6    | 678
```

I'm doing an inner join to compare the values from both tables:

```
SELECT ID_1, VALUES_1, TABLE_2.VALUES_2
FROM TABLE_1,TABLE_2
WHERE 
  TABLE_1.ID_1 = TABLE_2.ID_2 AND
  TABLE_1.VALUES_1 <> TABLE_2.VALUES_2
```

Which gives me the rows I am interested in,

```
ID_1 | VALUES_1 | VALUES_2
3    | 345      | 349
```

Is there a way to insert a third column as part of the query to display the difference between `VALUES_1` and `VALUES_2`? E.g.

```
ID_1 | VALUES_1 | VALUES_2 | DIFFERENCE
3    | 345      | 349      | 4
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the `-` operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    ID_1
    ,VALUES_1
    ,TABLE_2.VALUES_2
    ,TABLE_2.VALUES_2 - VALUES_1 as Differnce
FROM
    TABLE_1
    INNER JOIN TABLE_2
    ON TABLE_1.ID_1 = TABLE_2.ID_2
    AND TABLE_1.VALUES_1 <> TABLE_2.VALUES_2
```

Note I also converted your query to use explicit join syntax instead of implicit join as that is the more standard method.

Comment: Can I then use `Difference` as a sort of variable in an `AND` clause? E.g. `AND TABLE_1.VALUES_1 <> Difference`

Comment: @joshi123 No you would not be able to use it in a WHERE or an ON (AND) clause unless you made the entire query a derived table.  However  you should be able use it as a shortcut in an ORDER BY clause